# Posting specific theoretical questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have a theoretic question regarding a code concept in php.

My **idea** of how to solve it is **well-considered**, but I want to know **if other users may see errors in reasoning** and possible problems **with my solution**.

I would describe my idea very detailed, so others can follow my way of thinking and may suggest things to me or in best case say it's an appropriate way of solving it.

But *is Stack Overflow the right place to ask* such a question?

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Potential problem: you're asking a question which might not have one answer since multiple people mIght see multiple problems and it'd prompt discussion.

Comment: That's why I asked on meta where to post such a question as I thought it may not fit for Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have actual code that you want others to comment on, we have a site for that - [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

If it's a conceptual question, it may be a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have no actual code so I'm going to post on Programmers. Thanks for your answer!