# On which SE site should a question about the definition of logical operations be asked?

Tags: support, migration, site-recommendation

[What is the difference between Logical and Comparison operators in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20837444) was recently asked on SO.

Whilst the question was specifically phrased in relation to MySQL, it's clearly applicable to most languages and is actually seeking a *conceptual* distinction between different classes of operation rather than any solution to a practical problem faced in software development.  In particular, given that comparison operators are fairly easily understood, it's really seeking *a conceptual definition of logical operations*: the OP's [comment upon my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837444/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-and-comparison-operators-in-mysql#comment31253292_20837539) reinforces this view.

As such, it doesn't neatly fit within any of the categories that are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO.  I feel that (perhaps once edited to exclude references to specific languages) it might better belong on another, more theoretical, site within the SE network.

Indeed, I flagged it for moderator attention:

> I don't know on which SE site this question best belongs, but I have a feeling it isn't SO. Perhaps TCS? Or Philosophy? Or Math? Or maybe even Programmers?

But received the response:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

**What further action, if any, should I take?**

See also:

- [Where to ask question about logic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194693)
- [Posting specific theoretical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119646)

Comment: Well, What I personally did was upvote the question and one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this question is not about Logic itself. It's about how authors of MySQL categorize their operators, and how and why do they assign these particular names to these categories. There is no such thing as "comparison operator" in Logic AFAIK, there are just unary, binary, etc. operators, or relations.

In general, you're right, as you can strip the `MySQL` part and still consider a very similar topic. You can answer this type of question in regard to any programming paradigm, language, framework etc. or analyse typical nomenclature used in programming, so this probably fits better on "Programmers".

> What further action, if any, should I take?

Vote to close the question as off-topic. There is no "Programmers" migration option, so you should probably choose the generic off-topic reason.

Comment: Agreed.  My view (stated above) was that the question distils down to the *conceptual definition of logical operations*, and that such a question applies much more broadly than within the narrow context of MySQL and thus belongs elsewhere in the SE network.  However, in this case the moderators "found no evidence to support" this assertion (which we both share), so my question was about what action one should take?  I cannot believe that casting a close vote for being off-topic can really be the best solution for the OP or indeed the SE network as a whole.

Comment: @eggyal I agree as the question itself is not that bad. If I remember correctly the issue of not having tools to perform automatic migration to Programmers and other quite common sites was discussed here on meta, I don't remember the outcome though.

Comment: Why vote to close as off-topic? Regardless of whether the question would be on-topic elsewhere, it is on-topic where it is.

Comment: @Gilles I think it's a boundary case. I'm not sure whether it's off-topic, but I gave this advice because OP thinks it's off-topic. So I guess that's what close votes are for - to vote according to your judgement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question about terminology used in MySQL. That makes it on-topic on Stack Overflow. It's a question about programming technology.

Yes, the question is applicable in a wider context. It could work on Programmers. If could even fit on CS, but only because the term happens to be used in many languages, not just in (My)SQL, which the asker didn't know — we'd close a question about a specific language's terminology as off-topic. (Questions about specific languages are usually off-topic on CS — a CS question that's about a specific language would have to be about its semantics, not about its terminology.)

Since the question is not off-topic on SO, I think the moderator made the right call.

Comment: As I wrote above, I believe that (despite its wording) the question was really asking for some conceptual clarification over the general difference between logical operations and comparative ones; perhaps I am wrong and it was, after all, purely about MySQL terminology - in which case I would accept that the mod made the right call and the question does indeed belong on SO. But nevertheless my question here was, given that I hold a differing view, **what action should I take?** You have not helped to answer this question (other than by rejecting my premise) and so I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: @eggyal Uh? There's an on-topic, open question. If you have a differing view, you can air it on meta, which you already did. What else do you think you should do? What is your purpose here?

Comment: You're right - despite having actually done so, "air it on meta" is precisely the answer that I was struggling to grasp.